# From wide form to long form using gather function

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

Suppose that we have a data set including six variables and id variable like below:

```
id v2019 v2020 v2021 u2019 u2020 u2021
```

In this case, if we use Stata we can make this long form very easily using the "reshape" command like below.

reshape long v u, i(id) j(year)
=> id v u

But, when I use the gather function in tidyr package, this function makes just three columns every time.

```
data %>% gather(key = "key, value = "value")
```

=> id key value

that is gather function gathers "every" columb with out seperate of different variables suchs as u and v.

So my question is that how can I imitate the function of reshape in stata using gather in r.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but it sounds like you want to make your data in long form based off the "u" and "v" variables here. I think `pivot_longer` in the `tidyverse` package may be better. Here I have simulated a similar dataset and loaded the `tidyverse` packages:

```
#### Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Reproduce Data ####
data <- tibble(id = 1:20,
          v2019 = rnorm(n=20),
          v2020 = rnorm(n=20),
          v2021 = rnorm(n=20),
          u2019 = rnorm(n=20),
          u2020 = rnorm(n=20),
          u2021 = rnorm(n=20))
```

Then I pivoted the data by selecting which columns (specifying which contain "u" or "v" respectively), then named them "Variable" for the names of each u/v variable, then given their values a separate column.

```
#### Pivot Data ####
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(contains("v"),
                        contains("u")),
               names_to = "Variable",
               values_to = "Value")
```

Giving you this long form data with `id` first, your `Variable` column second with their names, and the `Value` column for each numeric value of each variable:

```
# A tibble: 120 × 3
      id Variable  Value
   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1 v2019     2.07 
 2     1 v2020    -1.78 
 3     1 v2021    -1.84 
 4     1 u2019     0.835
 5     1 u2020    -1.53 
 6     1 u2021     0.883
 7     2 v2019    -0.509
 8     2 v2020    -0.860
 9     2 v2021    -0.418
10     2 u2019     1.11
```

As a side note: I generally prefer using `gather` when I pant to pivot data very quickly and not think about it and `pivot_longer` when I'm trying to be much more specific.